# My TensorFlow model keeps making the same incorrect prediction no matter what

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, stackblitz

I'm learning [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), and I finished making a model that can predict handwritten digits using the [MNIST data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database). And it runs great when I test the model in my Python environment.

After making the model, I wanted to try making a web application with it, but for some reason when I make my predictions on the web application, my imported model keeps making the same incorrect prediction.

This is the code that I use for the drawing portion in my application:

```
export default function Draw() {
  const [guess, setGuess] = useState();
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const contextRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.style.width = `${window.innerWidth / 4}px`;
    canvas.style.height = `${window.innerHeight / 2}px`;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.scale(2, 2);
    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.lineWidth = 20;
    contextRef.current = context;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {}, [guess]);
  const startDrawing = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    contextRef.current.beginPath();
    contextRef.current.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);

    setIsDrawing(true);
  };

  const finishDrawing = () => {
    contextRef.current.closePath();
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

  const draw = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (!isDrawing) {
      return;
    }
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = nativeEvent;
    contextRef.current.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY);
    contextRef.current.stroke();
  };


  const reset = () => {
    console.log('hello');
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <canvas
          className={styles.draw}
          onMouseDown={startDrawing}
          onMouseUp={finishDrawing}
          onMouseMove={draw}
          ref={canvasRef}
        />
      </div>
      <h2 className={styles.description}>
        I believe the number you drew was: {guess}
      </h2>
      <button onClick={evaluate}>Evaluate</button>
      <button onClick={reset}>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then this is the handler function which passes the image drawn to my model:

```
const evaluate = async () => {
    // Import model
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bonzaii1/NumericPrediction/main/Model/model.json'
    );

    // Set image to a variable
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    let image = new Image(28, 28);
    var resizedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var resizedContext = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');
    resizedCanvas.height = '28';
    resizedCanvas.width = '28';

    resizedContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 28, 28);
    image = resizedCanvas.toDataURL('image.png');
    window.location.href = image;

    // Turn the image to a tensor
    let tfTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(resizedCanvas, 1);
    tfTensor = tfTensor.squeeze();
    tfTensor = tfTensor.div(255.0);
    tfTensor = tfTensor.expandDims(0);
    tfTensor = tfTensor.cast('float32');
    console.log(tfTensor.shape);

    // Run the image through the model
    let result = model.predict(tfTensor);
    const index = result.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0];
    result.print();
    setGuess(index);
  };
```

I’ve tried resizing the image a bunch of different times and methods, but it doesn’t work. It keeps throwing the same incorrect prediction for a bunch of different attempts.

The image my model expects is a (28, 28) input. So I’ve tried manipulating it so its like that and when I download it, the image seems fine in size and display. But why does my model keep making the same thing?

Comment: Re *"making a web application with it"*: In what context (server, local web server, some cloud thing, etc.)? Using what? [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)? [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29)? Something built into the development environment? What versions? On what platform (incl. versions)?